# LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle returning 401 for invalid token on anonymous route

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, jwt

I'm using this LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle with FosUserBundle.

I have this in security.yml :

```
firewalls:
    app:
        pattern: ^/api
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        lexik_jwt: ~
```

with the following access_control :

```
- { path: ^/api/user/action1, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
- { path: ^/api/user/action2, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

The behaviour I was expecting for /api/user/action2 is having access no matter what is inside the request header. However I'm getting a 401 in the case where the Authorization Bearer is set but not valid (it is ok with valid token or no Authorization Bearer at all).

My use case is I need to check in my controller if the user is logged in but if not, I still want to let that anonymous user access the route.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a specific firewall for the route/pattern you want allow for anonymous users :

```
action2:
    pattern: ^/api/user/action2
    anonymous: true
    lexik_jwt: ~
```

Then, just move your less-protected `access_control` just before the fully-protected :

```
- { path: ^/api/user/action2, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/api/user/action1, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

In this way, you are application doesn't care about an Authorization header, and all users can access the resource without JWT.

**Update**

Change the anonymous route's firewall to :

```
action2:
    pattern: ^/api/user/action2
    anonymous: true
    lexik_jwt: ~
```

And make the access_control accepting anonymous And fully authenticated users :

```
- { path: ^/api/user/action2, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY]  }
- { path: ^/api/user/action1, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Please use the same order and clear your cache correctly.

It's working well in my JWT/FOSUB application, if it doesn't work for you I'll give you a working ready-to-use example.

And the controller :

```
$currentToken = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();

if (is_object($currentToken->getUser())) {
    // Do your logic with the current user
    return new JsonResponse(['user' => $currentToken->getUser()->getUsername()]);
} else {
    return new JsonResponse(['user' => 'Anonymous']);
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: The thing is that if the user IS actually logged in, I want to be able to know who it is from this route with $this->getUser().

Comment: I've added changes to show you how retrieve the current user if the request is authenticated.

Comment: Also, you are not talking about this need in your question, only about how make your route doesn't care about an authorization header.

Comment: I might need to edit my question if it is unclear. Want I want is get the user information if his token is valid and get null user if his token is not valid or missing. But allow anyway to execute controller. Right now the problem is when the user has not valid token, he gets 401.

Comment: Wy don't try my answer ? The first part show how make your route accessible by users authenticated or not  (with or without any authorization header, valid or not). The second part (update) shows you how retrieve the user if it's authenticated. What is missing ?

Comment: See my second update, don't forget to clear the cache properly and follows the order (don't remove your original firewall, keep the two, and make the route available for all roles in your access_control), and remove the stateless attribute on the unprotected firewall. It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Does your 1st exemple (with incognito mode on) have a invalid token in header ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved your problem in this way:

```
    api_public:
        pattern: ^/api/v1/public
        anonymous: true
        lexik_jwt:
            authorization_header:
                enabled: false
                prefix:  Bearer
            query_parameter:
                enabled: false
                name:    bearer
    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        lexik_jwt:
            authorization_header:
                enabled: true
                prefix:  Bearer
            query_parameter:
                enabled: true
                name:    bearer
```

Answer (score 0):

#### *** For those landing here in 2022 ***

### To allow anonymous access with JWT

You must write your own **`JWTAuthenticator`** class -
([Code Source](https://digitalfortress.tech/php/jwt-authentication-with-symfony/))

```php
// src/Security/JWTAuthenticator.php
namespace App\Security;

use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\TokenExtractor\TokenExtractorInterface;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Guard\JWTTokenAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security\FirewallMap;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Services\JWTTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
// use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage; // For Symfony 4.4 and above

final class JWTAuthenticator extends JWTTokenAuthenticator
{
    private $firewallMap;

    public function __construct(
        JWTTokenManagerInterface $jwtManager,
        EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher,
        TokenExtractorInterface $tokenExtractor,
        // TokenStorage $tokenStorage, // For Symfony 4.4 and above
        FirewallMap $firewallMap
    ) {
        parent::__construct($jwtManager, $dispatcher, $tokenExtractor);
        // For Symfony 4.4 and above, use the next line instead of the above one
        // parent::__construct($jwtManager, $dispatcher, $tokenExtractor, $tokenStorage);

        $this->firewallMap = $firewallMap;
    }

    /* For Symfony 3.x and below */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            return parent::getCredentials($request);
        } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
            $firewall = $this->firewallMap->getFirewallConfig($request);
            // if anonymous is allowed, do not throw error
            if ($firewall->allowsAnonymous()) {
                return;
            }

            throw $e;
        }
    }

   /* For Symfony 4.x and above */
   public function supports(Request $request) {
        try {
            return parent::supports($request) && parent::getCredentials($request);
        } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
            $firewall = $this->firewallMap->getFirewallConfig($request);

            // if anonymous is allowed, skip authenticator
            if ($firewall->allowsAnonymous()) {
                return false;
            }

            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

Register this class as a service by adding the following to your **`services.yaml`** file

```yaml
app.jwt_authenticator:
        #autowire: false     # uncomment if you had autowire enabled.
        autoconfigure: false
        public: false
        parent: lexik_jwt_authentication.security.guard.jwt_token_authenticator
        class: App\Security\JWTAuthenticator
        arguments: ['@security.firewall.map']
```

Then update the firewall in **`security.yaml`** to use the newly registered service

```yaml
api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.jwt_authenticator
```

Lastly, here's a **[complete tutorial](https://digitalfortress.tech/php/jwt-authentication-with-symfony/)** to setup Lexik JWT bundle with Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add token extractor to config. I was wrong thinking this is enabled by default.

```yaml
# lexic_jwt_authentication.yaml
token_extractors:
    authorization_header:
        enabled: true
        prefix: Bearer
        name: Authorization
```